# android virtual device does not launch the emulator and gives error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

i am new to android development i have installed android studio 1.01. sdk and avd managers work fine but when i want to launch my virtual device it gave me this error:

```
C:\Users\-----\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_21

NAND: could not read file C:\Users\------\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/system-images\android-    21\google_apis\x86\/system.img, Invalid argument
```

i already searched both stackoverflow but didn't find any thing related :(

Comment: are you sure that you install all packages under  API 21 from SDK Manager? Please make sure that all installed correctly!

Comment: i have these packages installed for api 21 : sdk platform -google apis - source for android sdk - documentation for android sdk - google api intel x86

Comment: so please check everything under Android api 21 that is not installed and install them! also make sure that you installed from Tools "Android SDK Build-tools" for api 21!!

Comment: thanks. i downloaded them and now it works fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open sdk manager and make sure under API 21 system images are installed.